# C# "must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial"

Tags: c#

I'm not sure why i'm getting this error to be honest.

```
private int hour
{
    get;
    set
    {
        //make sure hour is positive
        if (value < MIN_HOUR)
        {
            hour = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Hour value " + value.ToString() + " cannot be negative. Reset to " + MIN_HOUR.ToString(),
                    "Invalid Hour", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            //take the modulus to ensure always less than 24 hours
            //works even if the value is already within range, or value equal to 24
            hour = value % MAX_HOUR;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried just doing an actual property:

```
public int hour 
{ 
    get; 
    set
    {
        //make sure hour is positive
        if (value < MIN_HOUR)
        {
            hour = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Hour value " + value.ToString() + " cannot be negative. Reset to " + MIN_HOUR.ToString(),
                    "Invalid Hour", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            //take the modulus to ensure always less than 24 hours
            //works even if the value is already within range, or value equal to 24
            hour = value % MAX_HOUR;
        }
    } 
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121940/automatic-properties-in-c-3-must-declare-a-body-for-get-if-i-declare-one-for-s

Comment: A quick note: It's a really bad idea to display UI in a setter.

Comment: if you do get; and set; then it's an auto property. if you define either one, it's no longer an auto property.

Comment: Also from what I see this code should throw a StackOverflowException after implementing the get accessor since you're not using a backing field for your property.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
private int hour;
public int Hour
{
    get { return hour; }
    set
    {
        //make sure hour is positive
        if (value < MIN_HOUR)
        {
            hour = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Hour value " + value.ToString() + " cannot be negative. Reset to " + MIN_HOUR.ToString(),
            "Invalid Hour", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            //take the modulus to ensure always less than 24 hours
            //works even if the value is already within range, or value equal to 24
            hour = value % MAX_HOUR;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An easier way to think about it, is get is declared, but not implemented.

Answer (score 31):

You need to provide a body for the `get;` portion as well as the `set;` portion of the property.

I suspect you want this to be:

```
private int _hour; // backing field
private int Hour
    {
        get { return _hour; }
        set
        {
            //make sure hour is positive
            if (value < MIN_HOUR)
            {
                _hour = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("Hour value " + value.ToString() + " cannot be negative. Reset to " + MIN_HOUR.ToString(),
                "Invalid Hour", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                //take the modulus to ensure always less than 24 hours
                //works even if the value is already within range, or value equal to 24
                _hour = value % MAX_HOUR;
            }
        }
    }
```

That being said, I'd also consider making this code simpler.  It's probably is better to use exceptions rather than a MessageBox inside of your property setter for invalid input, as it won't tie you to a specific UI framework.

If that is inappropriate, I would recommend converting this to a method instead of using a property setter.  This is especially true since properties have an implicit expectation of being "lightweight"- and displaying a MessageBox to the user really violates that expectation.

Comment: But would it be possible to use the automatic getter implementation with `abstract`, `extern`, or `partial`?

Answer (score 29):

You cannot provide your own implementation for the setter when using automatic properties. In other words, you should either do:

```
public int Hour { get;set;} // Automatic property, no implementation
```

*or* provide your own implementation for both the getter and setter, which is what you want judging from your example:

```
public int Hour  
{ 
    get { return hour; } 
    set 
    {
        if (value < MIN_HOUR)
        {
            hour = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Hour value " + value.ToString() + " cannot be negative. Reset to " + MIN_HOUR.ToString(),
                    "Invalid Hour", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
                //take the modulus to ensure always less than 24 hours
                //works even if the value is already within range, or value equal to 24
                hour = value % MAX_HOUR;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to either provide a body for both the getter and setter, or neither. Since you have non-trivial logic in your setter, you need a manually-implemented getter like so:

```
get { return _hour; }
```

If you decide you don't need the logic in the setter, you could go with an automatically-implemented property like so:

```
public int Hour { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5):

You DO NOT have to provide a body for getters and setters IF you'd like the automated compiler to provide a basic implementation.

This DOES however require you to make sure you're using the v3.5 compiler by updating your web.config to something like

```
 <compilers>
   <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
  </compiler>
</compilers>
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error message because I had a function with a parameter named with a reserved word.

```
   public int SaveDelegate(MyModel.Delegate delegate)
```

Renaming the variable delegate solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the keywork value to accomplish this.

```
public int Hour {
    get{
        // Do some logic if you want
        //return some custom stuff based on logic

        // or just return the value
        return value;
    }; set { 
        // Do some logic stuff 
        if(value < MINVALUE){
            this.Hour = 0;
        } else {
            // Or just set the value
            this.Hour = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5idNW.png)I had the same problem here:

```
    private static void swapMth(ref int x, ref int y);
    {
        int num = x;
        x = y;
        y = num;
    }


    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
        labelResult.Text = $"Befor      n1 = {x} , n2={y} ";
        swapMth(ref x, ref y);
        labelResult.Text += $"\n After  n1 = {x} , n2={y}";
    }
```

And it was solved by deleting ";" from the method line:

private static void swapMth(ref int x, ref int y);     PROBLEM

to

private static void swapMth(ref int x, ref int y)      SOLVED

I know it is basic mistake, hope someone could get help by this note.

```
    private static void swapMth(ref int x, ref int y)
    {
        int num = x;
        x = y;
        y = num;
    }


    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
        labelResult.Text = $"Befor      n1 = {x} , n2={y} ";
        swapMth(ref x, ref y);
        labelResult.Text += $"\n After  n1 = {x} , n2={y}";
    }
```

Comment: What is your code demonstrating, why does it define methods and not properties, and why is it completely different than the code in the question?  If you solved your issue by deleting `;` (from where?) then it probably wasn't the same problem.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your comments. Here is picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/5idNW.png  It is the same problem as the title

Comment: There is more to a question than the title, though.  If you read the body, too, you'll see that this question is specifically about properties, with no mention of methods.  What `;` are you proposing be deleted from the code in the question to solve that problem?  Removing any one of them would cause a compiler error.

Comment: I am super stupid, idk how I missed that in my code lol, Thanks.