# Overriding DbContext get; set;

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a `DbSet<Photo>` that I would like to use as a proxy to actual  objects:

```
   public DbSet<Photo> Photos {
        get { return (DbSet<Photo>)DbPhotos.Where(s => !s.ToDelete); }
        set; // compilation error
    }
```

For some reason, `set` is unhappy saying `Accessor must declare a body`.

How do I implement the default `set` behavior while overriding the `get`?

Comment: If get or set has a body, they both must have a body (they are no longer auto-properties).  Duplicated by a few other questions, including: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810415/c-sharp-must-declare-a-body-because-it-is-not-marked-abstract-extern-or-parti](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810415/c-sharp-must-declare-a-body-because-it-is-not-marked-abstract-extern-or-parti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the braces.

```
public DbSet<Photo> Photos {
    get { return (DbSet<Photo>)DbPhotos.Where(s => !s.ToDelete); }
    set {}
}
```

As another commenter said, as soon as you give either `get` or `set` a body, the property is no longer an auto-property. So the syntax won't allow you to treat it as such.