# Call One Event From Another

Tags: c#, .net, events

I'm trying to create an abstraction layer for a timer. Basically, the idea is to create a class which abstracts two individual timers. Basically, the timer abstraction class should trigger an event when it is "off" and another when it turns "on." So, for example, if this were a traffic light, timer1 would control the green light and timer 2 would control the red (let's ignore yellow).

So as you can see, `timer1_Elapsed` and `timer2_Elapsed`handle the "daisy chaining" of the timers. After these events occur, I want another event (the real purpose of this timer" to occur.

The problem, it seems, is that my `Event1` and `Event2` `ElapsedEventHandler`s don't seem to work as intended. I'm getting the following error:
`'TwoCycleTimer.Event1.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial` and the same thing for `Event2`

I should note, declaring a body for the `get` did nothing, just made things worse.

`get {return timer1.Elapsed; };` resulted in a  `can only appear on the left hand side of += or =` error

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class TwoCycleTimer
{
    private Boolean enabled;    
    private Timer timer1;
    private Timer timer2;

public Boolean Enabled
{
    get { return enabled; }
    set 
    {
        timer1.Enabled = value;
        enabled = value;
    }
}

public double Interval1
{
    get { return timer1.Interval; }
    set { timer1.Interval = value; }
}

public double Interval2
{
    get { return timer2.Interval; }
    set { timer2.Interval = value; }
}

public ElapsedEventHandler Event1 { get; set { timer1.Elapsed += value; } }
public ElapsedEventHandler Event2 { get; set { timer2.Elapsed += value; } }

public TwoCycleTimer(bool Enabled = false, double Interval1 = 4000, double Interval2 = 60000, ElapsedEventHandler Event1 = null, ElapsedEventHandler Event2 = null)
{
    timer1 = new Timer(Interval1);
    timer2 = new Timer(Interval2);

    timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
    timer2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer2_Elapsed);


    if(Event1 != null)
        timer1.Elapsed += Event1;
    if(Event2 != null)
        timer2.Elapsed += Event2;

    this.Enabled = enabled;
}

private void timer1_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Enabled)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer2.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void timer2_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Enabled)
    {
        timer2.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're getting this issue because you are declaring a body for the `set` but not the `get` accessor. Try just raising the timer events privately, then calling your custom events and making them public.

Comment: @davisj1691 I will try doing it privately like you say. Please see my updated question though, I mention that adding a body causes other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing currently is that of having a body for your `set` accessor but not the `get` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810415/c-sharp-must-declare-a-body-because-it-is-not-marked-abstract-extern-or-parti) for the basics). From my understanding (and [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)) there is no need for a body in either accessor with events (nor do I think it is allowed either). The simplest solution for your goal is to raise the timer events privately (which should be the default) and use those events to call your custom events:

```
using System.Timers;
internal class DualTimer {

    #region Fields

    private Timer leftTimer;
    private Timer rightTimer;

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public event EventHandler LeftTick;
    public event EventHandler RightTick;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor(s)

    public DualTimer(int leftInterval, int rightInterval) {
        leftTimer = new Timer(leftInterval);
        rightTimer = new Timer(rightInterval);
        leftTimer.Elapsed += leftTimer_Elapsed;
        rightTimer.Elapsed += rightTimer_Elapsed;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public void Start() {
        leftTimer.Start();
        rightTimer.Start();
    }
    public void Stop() {
        leftTimer.Stop();
        rightTimer.Stop();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void leftTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        LeftTick(sender, e);
    }
    private void rightTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        RightTick(sender, e);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

This will hide the events for the individual timers as they are private objects to the class. When their elapsed events are raised, your left and right tick events will be raised respectively. This can be easily expaned to add your yellow light (very good analogy by the way). The implementation for this class is incredibly straight-forward:

```
static DateTime startTime;
static void Main(string[] args) {
    DualTimer t = new DualTimer(100, 250);
    t.LeftTick += T_LeftTick;
    t.RightTick += T_RightTick;
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    t.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
    t.Stop();
}
private static void T_LeftTick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Right side tick. {DateTime.Now - startTime}");
}
private static void T_RightTick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Left side tick. {DateTime.Now - startTime}");
}
```

A good read for this issue would be the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2(v=vs.100).aspx) tutorial for implementing events in your class.

> The following procedures describe how to implement an event in a class. The first procedure implements an event that does not have associated data; it uses the classes `System.EventArgs` and `System.EventHandler` for the event data and delegate handler. The second procedure implements an event with custom data; it defines custom classes for the event data and the event delegate handler.

The tutorial is quite thorough and has a lot of information on events (with and without data). Feel free to give it a read to learn further.

Comment: Ahh, I see, thank you! I'm kind of mediocre when it comes to lambda expressions (I'm mostly a C/C++ coder) though, the last two lines are giving me an issue still. Telling me that LeftTick and RightTick must have a return type

Comment: In which portion, the class or the implementation? Everything compiles for me; however, I will break the expressions down to full bodied methods for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Yes, the class portion (last-couple lines). I'm on VS2010, so maybe it's a .NET incompatibility thing. But it loks like you've broken it down (as have I) and mine is compiling as well now

Comment: Sounds great! Glad everything is working as expected; make sure you mark as answer if the post solved your issues. As for the incompatibility, the ability to use expression bodied methods was introduced in C# 6. I don't think that is available in VS2010.