# Asking for body variable in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am Trying to make a jump script in unity but i always get this error

```
Assets\JumpScript.cs(8,6): error CS0501: 'JumpScript.Start()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
```

### This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JumpScript : MonoBehaviour
{
void Start();

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            GetComponent<RigidBody> ().AddForce (Vector3.up *1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# "must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810415/c-sharp-must-declare-a-body-because-it-is-not-marked-abstract-extern-or-parti)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
void Start();
```

to

```
void Start()
{

}
```