# CS0501 error with dependancy service code

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am fairly new to C sharp and have this error with the Microsoft dependancy service .The error says the code requires a body as not abstract, partial or extern but the Microsoft info says use static.
The 3 lines of code that have the same error are as follows and the errors are with 'Get','Register','Resolve'?
public static IOSBluetooth Get
(Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget fetchTarget = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget.GlobalInstance) where IOSBluetooth : class;

```
    public static void Register<IOSBluetooth>() where IOSBluetooth : class;
    public static IOSBluetooth Resolve<IOSBluetooth>(Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget fallbackFetchTarget = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget.GlobalInstance) where IOSBluetooth : class;
```

Comment: Is this your code or something generated? The code you are showing here, doesn't specify bodies for the methods, that is the error. Is this an Interface you are trying to implement? Perhaps you mean to remove `public static` infront of the method signatures then.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.dependencyservice?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: This code is from the Microsoft dependency service info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.dependencyservice?view=xamarin-forms .I am trying to access classes and objects in the IOS section of a Xamarin project from the main implementation. Tried your suggestion of removing 'public static' and the same error occurs. Regards Nick.

Comment: It is really unclear where this error occurs. Can you add a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: I think you can add a screenshot to your question so we can see the errors.

Comment: https://ibb.co/cg6FDGG

Comment: There we go finally

Comment: https://ibb.co/WnPK9Qd Better . Shows the 9 errors. All with the same code I first posted. Nick.

Comment: Obviously,the error is `must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial"`,please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810415/c-sharp-must-declare-a-body-because-it-is-not-marked-abstract-extern-or-parti) on how to fix this similar issue.Also,please refer to our [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/registration-and-resolution) on how to use `dependency service`.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your very kind and helpful reply. I think I get you. So I should put" { some logic code} " below my code? Regards nick

Comment: Says "{" and "}" invalid tokens by the way. Bit confused. Regards Nick.

Comment: Hi Nick,looks like it's a semantic error for C#.Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo or post your code to your question?Thanks!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RbWVWCR7w_t7TbhNjL4CEkDNTzPMPb3A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Alexander, here the project with Bin and Object folders removed to make it smaller. You can see the errors in the Main.xaml.cs file and hopefully you can see I'm trying to create an app that discovers and downloads from a bluetooth low energy enabled instrument. The original ble code was written by a developer and I am using dev express UI controls and they say that the elements class ie DiscoverItems and StrResult have to be in the main implementation for data binding with their data grid so suggested I use dependancy service to access them in the iOS section which they need to be to work.

Comment: https://github.com/nickblair762/TME-project-code/upload . Hi Alexander,here a minimal reproducible example. Same errors as my project if you could kindly have a look? Best regards. Nick.

Comment: sorry its https://github.com/nickblair762/TME-project-code

Comment: Hi Nick,Sorry for the late response!Looks like you're using `dependency service` in your project.Please go through this docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction to get a better understanding of this concept.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I've got a better understanding now. I'll give it a go. Regards nick